# opencv: Invalid number of channels in input image

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image with this shape:

```
(300,512,2)
```

I want to convert it to grayscale, I'm using this code:

```
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(open_cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

but getting an error:

```
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 2
```

I understand that `cvtColor` requires 3 channels. But I have only 2. What can I do now?

Comment: what _are_ those two channels?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this works:

```
grayscale = open_cv_image[:, :, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

BGR to GRAY expects 3 channels . But your image has 2 channels and it will not work.

When you do

```py
grayscale = open_cv_image[:, :, 0]
```

you are considering first channel as gray.

Comment: I don't get it. Is it a correct way? `grayscale = open_cv_image[:, :, 0]`

Comment: Generally color images are 3 (red,green and blue)or 4 channels (red,green,blue and alpha) , but gray images are 1 channel. In your case I am not sure how you got 2 channels .